# Loop closure - Where do I put it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, closures

In relation to a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635488/javascript-trello-json-array-loop-counter-scope), I am having a hard time figuring out where to put a loop closure for an array I am using to match against **JSON** returns.

Below is my revised code:

```
$(function()
{
    var $reports = $('#repOut');
    var techCount = 0;
    var repCount = 0;
    techs = ["Name_1", "Name_2"];

    function counts(tech, count)
    {
        this.tech = tech;
        this.count = count;
    }
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.trello.com/1/board/BOARD_ID/checklists?checkItem_fields=name,state&key=MY_KEY&token=MY_TOKEN',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data)
        {
            $.each(data, function(i, repName)
            {
                var items = repName.checkItems;
                for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
                {
                    for (var n = 0; n < techs.length; n++)
                    {
                        techName = techs[n];
                    }
                    var rex = new RegExp(techName, "i");
                    var num = /\(\d+\)/;
                    if (rex.test(items[i].name))
                    {
                        var repFull = items[i].name;
                        repName = repFull.replace(/\.*$|-.*$/, "");
                        if (num.test(items[i].name))
                        {
                            var repNum = parseInt(/\d+/.exec(items[i].name), 10);
                            repCount += repNum;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            var techCount = new counts(techName, repCount);
            $reports.after("<table border =1 id='reports'><tr><th>Tech</th><th>Count</th></tr><tr><td>" + techCount.tech + "</td><td>" + techCount.count + "</td></td></tr></table>");
        }
    });
});
```

The loop only returns the **JSON** values for `Name_2` (but this time, it is added up correctly and displayed on my webpage). I need to get these values for **EACH** name in my `techs` array and output them. I have read many websites/articles/answers about closures and I just cannot wrap my head around where/how to put it in my code!

Can anyone help provide an example of what my code would look like with a closure? Am I even right in suspecting a closure is needed?

Comment: You are missing the `var` keyword for `techs`, `i`, `techName` and `repName`, though in the cases of `i` and `repName` you are overwriting your function parameters. On purpose?

Comment: no, I don't think there is any closure required. It looks like you just messed up your loop structure.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting. Can you spot your mistake yourself now? Hint: that loop over `techs`…

Comment: The scope of the techs loop should probably be expanded - now, it is doing the loop and stopping at key 1 and then continuing....?

Comment: you are always going to set techName to "Name_2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the feedback! I guess I just needed someone "looking over my shoulder" to help me see the obvious problems. Below is the fixed code with my comments.

```
$(function()
{
    var $reports = $('#repOut');
    var techCount = 0;
    var techs = ["Name_1", "Name_2"];

    function counts(tech, count)
    {
        this.tech = tech;
        this.count = count;
    }
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.trello.com/1/board/BOARD_ID/checklists?checkItem_fields=name,state&key=KEY&token=TOKEN',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data)
        {
            for (var n = 0; n < techs.length; n++) //MOVED THE 'tech' LOOP UP HERE
            {
                var techName = techs[n]; //INCLUDING THE 'techName' VARIABLE DEFINITION
                var repCount = 0;
                $.each(data, function(_, repName)
                {
                    var items = repName.checkItems;
                    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
                    {
                        var rex = new RegExp(techName, "i");
                        var num = /\(\d+\)/;
                        if (rex.test(items[i].name))
                        {
                            var repFull = items[i].name;
                            var repFullName = repFull.replace(/\.*$|-.*$/, "");
                            if (num.test(items[i].name))
                            {
                                var repNum = parseInt(/\d+/.exec(items[i].name), 10);
                                repCount += repNum;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                //MOVED MY OBJECT DECLARATION UP IN THE LOOP
                var techCount = new counts(techName, repCount); 
                $reports.after("<table border =1 id='reports'><tr><th>Tech</th><th>Count</th><tr><td>" + techCount.tech + "</td><td>" + techCount.count + "</td><br></td></tr></table>");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Great! I made some further adjustments.

Comment: I'd also recommend to omit the superfluous `var techCount = 0;` and `var repFull = items[i].name; var repFullName = repFull.replace(/\.*$|-.*$/, "");` declarations that you actually never use anywhere.